# Imagemagick: Convert PNG lost "image data"

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I'm using this command and all I get is an empty black image:

```
convert image.png image.tif
```

All I need is the same image in `tif` and with a white background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original PNG has a transparent background. If you want to convert to a non-transparent background (which is done implicitly if the target format does not support transparency), you should specify yourself the desired color. 
I believe something like this should work

```
   convert image.png -background white -flatten -alpha off image.tif
```

For details, see [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#remove).

Answer (score 2):

It's because the transparent background is automatically converted to black colour. So your output is as expected - black text on black background...

You need to set white background, flatten the image and remove transparency before converting to tiff. So use:

```
 convert input.png -background white -flatten -alpha off output.tif
```

See more at:
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#remove